# Error with the "no. of answers" on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

I was browsing new posts and I found that a question that actually had 2 answers displayed 1 on the home screen.

The question was "How to get others interested in restating an old campaign"

[image: homescreen]
[image: answers]

Comment: It's probably just caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not really a bug.

The app caches the state of the posts *only once* when they are retrieved on refreshing the feed, and it's never been intended to be updated in realtime.

Refreshing the feed after that will only try to get new feed items, but not refreshing existing items.

---

In this case, when the app retrieved the hot question on RPG.SE, it had only 1 answer. Shortly before you opened the question, a new answer was posted (as it can be seen from "just now" timestamp).

Comment: I was the one who answerd the second answere to that post. U can chek if u want to. Thats why i asked this one

Comment: Yea pretty sad how the feed only gets the items and doesn't update the all country system.

Comment: I sent python response works fine after test (coc) share.